# How to Calculate Rolling Statistics Over a 3-Day Window in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a DataFrame where each row represents a user's contribution on a given date, like this:

[image]

I would like to add two new columns (**focal_user_contribution_3day** and **average_contribution_3day**) based on the contribution over a 3-day rolling window.

For example, for the row with index 7, the 3-day window is from 1/25/23 to 1/28/23. In this window, we have:

- User 1: 1 byte contribution
- User 2: 3 bytes contribution
- User 3: 72 bytes contribution (65+7)

The average contribution for this window would then be (1 + 3 + 72)/3 = 26.3

How can I perform this operation efficiently using Python and pandas?

Comment: Use Pandas rolling [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use [`Series.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')

df['focal_user_contribution_3day'] = df['contribution'].rolling('3D', closed='left').sum()

df['Average_contribution_3day'] = df['contribution'].rolling('3D', closed='left').mean()
```

Comment: No, the output is not what I expect as shown in the table. But thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @Houhouhia - How is count `72` ? 3+4+65? Why is `User 2: 3 bytes contribution` ?

Comment: 72=7+65 based on the 6th and 7th rows of contributions. @ jezrael

Comment: @Houhouhia - Hoiw is count `User 2: 3 bytes contribution`